# Comparing date ranges for same asset (mulitple rows?)(T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey ladies and gentlemen,

I am pretty new to T-SQl but I need to know if this is even possible. I have data that looks like this:

```
location_id,initial_date,final_date,asset_id,fixed_fee,uid
1,1/1/2005 0:00,11/3/2010 0:00,10025,21,22T0TG9UT 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,7/26/2010 0:00,10026,21,22T0TG8AC 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,7/26/2010 0:00,10027,21,22T0TG8AF 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/20/2011 0:00,10028,21,22T0TG8AI 
1,6/13/2011 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10028,12.5,38P0WGUV3 
1,4/20/2011 0:00,6/13/2011 0:00,10028,21,3770QEMG1 
1,4/20/2011 0:00,6/13/2011 0:00,10029,21,3770QEUYX 
1,6/13/2011 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10029,12.5,38P0WH6G4 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/20/2011 0:00,10029,21,22T0TG8AK 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,6/13/2011 0:00,10030,21,22T0TG8AM 
1,6/13/2011 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10030,12.5,38P0WHG30 
1,6/13/2011 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10031,12.5,38P0WHN50 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,6/13/2011 0:00,10031,21,22T0TG8AR 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/14/2014 0:00,10158,21,22T0TG8AW 
1,4/15/2014 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10158,12.5,41M0TAZNL 
1,4/15/2014 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10159,12.5,41M0TBXIS 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/14/2014 0:00,10159,21,22T0TG8B0 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/14/2014 0:00,10160,21,22T0TG8B2 
1,4/15/2014 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10160,12.5,41M0TCKZM 
1,4/15/2014 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10161,12.5,41M0TD5P7 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,4/14/2014 0:00,10161,21,22T0TG8BH 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,7/26/2010 0:00,10162,21,22T0TG8BJ 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,11/3/2010 0:00,10163,21,22T0TG8BL 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,7/26/2010 0:00,10164,21,22T0TG8BN 
1,12/13/2010 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10333,15,33L0OR1MH 
1,12/13/2010 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10334,15,33L0ORB5R 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10336,5,22T0TG8BQ 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10337,5,22T0TG8BR 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10338,5,22T0TG8BT 
1,1/1/2005 0:00,12/31/2048 0:00,10339,5,22T0TG8BV
```

What I am running into is, some asset's get moved or the fee structure on them changes. At which time they are given an final_date (12/31/2048 is just a place holder end date), and then a new asset is created with the same information, but a new initial date, UID, and final_date of 12/31/2048.

The dates are not allowed to overlap, and it seems to be causing a ton of other errors. If the fee structure changes on Jan 1, the next date listed has to be Jan2. So I would need to use some T-SQL that would check each date range against the next date range wherever an asset_id and a location_id match across multiple rows.

I would appreciate any advice or general guidance on this. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible to solve problems like this with SQL!

First I came up with this solution, which is fairly straight-forward.
It simply looks at all the records in the table that have a matching record (based on asset id and location id) where the date ranges overlap, using the BETWEEN operator to check the possible combinations.

```
SELECT
    A.[uid],
    A.[location_id],
    A.[asset_id],
    A.[initial_date],
    A.[final_date],
    A.[fixed_fee]
FROM [tbl] A
WHERE   EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM [tbl] B
                WHERE   A.[location_id] = B.[location_id]
                    AND A.[asset_id] = B.[asset_id]
                    AND A.[uid] != B.[uid]
                    AND (
                            A.[initial_date] BETWEEN B.[initial_date] AND B.[final_date]
                         OR A.[final_date] BETWEEN B.[initial_date] AND B.[final_date]
                         OR B.[initial_date] BETWEEN A.[initial_date] AND A.[final_date]
                         OR B.[final_date] BETWEEN A.[initial_date] AND A.[final_date]
                        )
            )
ORDER BY 
    A.[location_id],
    A.[asset_id],
    A.[initial_date]
```

...but then I felt like getting a little more creative and came up with this one too. It gives the same results, but this one builds a range of all possible dates, then joins that up to the data to find which asset + location combinations have multiple entries, then it returns all the records it finds.

```
WITH [cte_min_max] AS
    (
        SELECT
            MIN([initial_date]) [min_date],
            MAX([initial_date]) [max_date]
        FROM #tbl
    ),
[cte_recursion] AS
    (
        SELECT
            [min_date] [date],
            [max_date]
        FROM [cte_min_max]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date]),
            [max_date]
        FROM [cte_recursion]
        WHERE   [date] <= [max_date]
    ),
[cte_duplicates] AS
    (
        SELECT
            A.[date],
            B.[location_id],
            B.[asset_id]
        FROM [cte_recursion] A
        INNER JOIN #tbl B
        ON      A.[date] BETWEEN B.[initial_date] AND B.[final_date]
        GROUP BY 
            A.[date],
            B.[location_id],
            B.[asset_id]
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    )
SELECT
    A.[uid],
    A.[location_id],
    A.[asset_id],
    A.[initial_date],
    A.[final_date],
    A.[fixed_fee]
FROM #tbl A
WHERE   EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM [cte_duplicates] B
                WHERE   A.[location_id] = B.[location_id]
                    AND A.[asset_id] = B.[asset_id]
                    AND B.[date] IN (A.[initial_date], A.[final_date])
            )
ORDER BY 
    A.[location_id],
    A.[asset_id],
    A.[initial_date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: By the power of grey skull. Thank you!